# Save H264 encoded stream without re-encoding

Tags: gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipeline that streams using :

```
v4l2src ! x264enc ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=ip port=8554
```

And this pipeline that receives this stream :

```
                                                                /   queue !     avdec_h264 ! appsink
udpsrc ! capsfilter ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! tee ! 
                                                                \   queue ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink
```

Simplified receiver pipeline without the tee is :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8080 caps="lots-of-caps" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/home/rish/Desktop/recorded.264 -e
```

Question : 
Is there a way to save the H264 encoded stream received from udpsrc without having to re-encode it? How do I correctly close the filesink?

What I've tried so far : The discussion from [this](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2012-May/035999.html) thread suggests the pipeline I've tried above but file is still corrupt. (not correctly closed).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840509/how-to-save-a-rtsp-video-stream-to-mp4-file-via-gstreamer) question asks a similar question. However I do not want to decode and re-encode. Another answer in the thread suggests using matroskamux element instead of mp4mux. This works, but I'd rather prefer using mp4mux (no particular reason, but I'd like to know why matroskamux works and mp4mux doesn't).

Comment: I would recommend you look at `splitmuxsink` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline is already muxing without re-encoding, there is no encoder on your pipeline. `h264parse` is just a parser.

you've already got an answer on how to close the stream here: [Sending EoS to filesink while removing branch from tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908694/sending-eos-to-filesink-while-removing-branch-from-tee/42914232?noredirect=1#comment72943315_42914232)

Comment: Yes, but the pipelines I've mentioned don't work. Once I start the stream using the first pipeline (udpsink), and receive using the second pipeline, the file saved is corrupt/unplayable. On replacing the muxer element (mp4mux) with matroskamux, the file saved is correct/playable. 

Also, follow up to the sending the EoS in this slightly more complex pipeline, to which element would I send the EoS to? There are no encoders/decoders in the receiver recording branch pipeline.

Comment: Got it! Sending the EoS to the muxer in this case worked. For anyone who may want to have a look at the source, find it [here](https://gist.github.com/CreaRo/bb2103d296fd2c5c3b39d4b82250b68a). (Any suggestions to the code are appreciated.)

@thiagoss, thanks a lot for the help! I'm still not sure as to why matroskamux works and mp4mux doesn't.

Comment: Both should work when you send EOS properly to the muxer branch. If without that matroska works it might be because the way the non-finished files are written by it are more recoverable than mp4mux does, mostly because of how those formats work.

How does mp4mux fails? File is not playable?

Comment: Doesnt work when I send the EoS to the mp4mux. If you could, please do try running the commandline pipelines I've mentioned in the question. Without the muxers if I save the encoded stream directly, file is not playable (gst-play complains 'could not determine type of stream') Also, I think you are - matroskamux is more recoverable than mp4mux. File saved muxing using mp4mux is unplayable (gst-play complains file is corrupt). The file with matroskamux is playable, but there is an initial patch of grey/sobel-edge like lines for the first 2-3 seconds. Also, the video saved is jittery.

Comment: Without a muxer it is not supposed to generate a playable file, only certain codecs already contain a fully parseable format, most will require them to be put inside a muxer to be able to be interpreted properly.

Comment: Both mp4 and matroska muxers should work if you send the EOS event to them (or to the encoders before them) and wait for the sink to post an EOS message before shutting down them. Without the EOS they won't finish the file properly and the result might not be playable or optimal.